# Delete specific stack activity

Tags: android, activity-stack

In my application I have a sequence of 5 activitys, which from the second, there is the restart button, this should go back to first, the problem is that the stack still holds, which creates a problem, since the user can click back. Clearing the entire stack is not an option as there is an activity before these 5, and if I clean it, it will also be erased.

**Using fragments is not an option**

Comment: try `android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest or `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

Comment: Can you explain it bit more?

Comment: @PankajKumar, So, the first activity is a menu, when clicking on an option it opens another activity that is a sequence, type, in this new I click it goes to another, then click the other and it goes to next, but if I click " restart "it goes back to the first after the menu, so I would have to erase the others and leave the menu alone, understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `singleTask` launchMode for the activity which you starts on tap of restart.

> singleTask

If there is no that singleTask Activity instance existed in the system yet, new one would be created and simply placed on top of stack in the same Task.

*But if there is an existed one, all of Activities placed above that `singleTask` Activity would be automatically and cruelly destroyed in the proper way (lifecycle trigged) to make that an Activity you want to appear on top of stack.* In the mean time, an `Intent` would be sent to the `singleTask Activity` through the lovely `onNewIntent()` method.

---

So you need to write activity entry in manifest as

```
<activity
    android:name=".YouSecondActivity"
    android:label="singleTask launchMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Please see `android:taskAffinity` documentation also. Although you do not require here but you should know about it.

References are [Understand Android Activity's launchMode: standard, singleTop, singleTask and singleInstance](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) and [Android Activity “launchMode” Explained , Must know for Android Development.](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-activity-launchmode-explained-cbc6cf996802)